# WPF datagrid getting changed value from grid and catiching it in viewmodel (nut current value)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, inline-editing

xaml file:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="BrugerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding Brugere, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RowEditEndingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=BrugerDataGrid}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <!-- DataGrid columns -->
```

viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bruger> Brugere { get; set; }

public ICommand RowEditEndingCommand => new RelayCommand<Object>(OnRowEditEnding);

private void OnRowEditEnding(Bruger bruger)
{
    // bruger is autogenerated from entity framework

}
```

the bruger i am reciving is the value before data is changed in the grid. how can i get the value after i have changed it , so that i can store the changed data to my database

I have been trying to add an event on this methos,

private void OnRowEditEnding(Bruger bruger,DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)

but that will give me an error on this line:
public ICommand RowEditEndingCommand => new RelayCommand(OnRowEditEnding);
Saying:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<Admin.DBAccess.Models.Bruger?>'

i thought PassEventArgsToCommand="True" maybe would allow me to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RowEditEnding` event occurs *before* a row edit is committed or canceled.

What you should do is to implement the [IEditableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) interface in your `Bruger` class and handle the logic in the `EndEdit()` method.

The other option would be to explicitly commit the edit in an event handler in the view:

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_handle)
    {
        _handle = false;
        BrugerDataGrid.CommitEdit();
        var updatedItem = e.Row.Item as Bruger;
        var viewModel = this.DataContext as YourViewModel;
        if (updatedItem != null && viewModel != null)
            viewModel.RowEditEndingCommand.Execute(updatedItem);
        _handle = true;
    }
}
```

Passing event args to a view model breaks the MVVM design pattern. Invoking a command programmatically in the code-behind of a view does not.

Comment: Thanks :-)My Bruger Class is autogenerated from entity framework..... would it be best to go for the second sollution then. sorry i am new to MVVM and wpf